# $a_{m}$ and $a_{n}$ are coprime if and only if $|m-n|=k$(General 2015 RMM)

Tags: number-theory

when I solve [RMM 2015 Problem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h627236_only_consecutive_terms_are_coprime), I think general is also hold

show that : for each $k\in N^{+}$. there exist an infinite sequence of postive integers $\color{#0a0}{\text{$a_{1},a_{2},\cdots$}}$ such that
$a_{m}$ and $a_{n}$ are coprime if and only if $\color{#0a0}{\text{$|m-n|=k$}}$

$k=1$ case is RMM 2015 fisrt problem,solution also see link.

when $k\to\infty$ is also right?

Comment: So are you asking for, for each $k$, a sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ that satisfies $a_m$ is coroner to $a_n$ of and only if $|m-n|=k$?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true for every $k$, just take $b_n = a_{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} + 1 \rfloor}$  where $(a_n)$ is a sequence for $k = 1$. What do you mean precisely by $k \to \infty$?

Comment: when $k\to \infty$,then $[\dfrac{n-1}{k}+1]\to 1?$

Comment: For fixed $n$, yes. I don't know why you're asking though.